# angular get and set atributes via service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-services

i can't find a solution to this, basicly everytime i do a login, i want to store the user that i get from the node end point in the service, after that in my main Controller i should get the name of the user, but that never happen, dunno why

**here is the code:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state,$location,$http,user) {

    $scope.user = {
        nome: user.getProperty()
    };

    $scope.showRegister = function () {
        $state.go('register');
    }

    $scope.showLogin = function () {
        $state.go('login');
    }

});

app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http, $state,user) {
    $scope.login = function () {

        var data = {};
        data.password = $scope.loja.password;
        data.email = $scope.loja.email;
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/login/',data) 
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            user.setProperty(data.nome);
            $state.go('home');
        })
        .error(function (statusText) {
            console.log("failed");
        });
    }
});
```

**user service**

```
app.service('user', function () {
    var property = {};
    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return property.nome;
        },
        setProperty: function (value) {
            property.nome = value;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Are you using angular service to share the data between controllers. If yes, then please share the code for user service?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: you are using `data.nome`  I think you first check for that it is `data.name` or  `data.nome` ?

Comment: try and change app.service(......); to app.factory(.......);

Comment: it is data.nome

Comment: chaning to factory gave me the same result :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just watch your service for changes by adding this code to your MainCtrl:

```
    $scope.$watch(function () { return user.getProperty();}, updateProp, true);
    function updateProp(newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.user = {
        nome: newValue
      };
    }
```

updateProp gets executed everytime the value of user.getProperty() changes.

Comment: $scope.$watch effects angular performance. I will prefer you should use events.

Comment: this is correct if performance is an issue you should probably use events like ARUN suggested in his solution, watch executes everytime a value gets changed in the scope

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is with your `MainCtrl` . In the initial execution of `MainCtrl` there is no value set into your service so its get blank. `MainCtrl` executes before setting the value in the service.

```
$scope.user = {
        nome: user.getProperty()
};
```

this code should be executed after setting the value in the service but it executes in the initialization of controller.

You can get the reference from the fiddle below.

`http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9799/`

Comment: ok i understand that, but how can i set the value for that outside of my maincontroller, i actually need to set it on my mainController view :S

Comment: you are using routing ?

Comment: yes i am using Ui-router, basicly i have that mainCtrl in the masterpage and that page just has the navbar i want to put the name there and change some stuf based if that user scope is empty or not, hope you understood :)

Comment: if it is a navbar then write `$scope.user = {
        nome: user.getProperty()
};` in function and use the cocept of angular custom events to evecutes that function when the response receive.

Comment: i just wanted to store that object in the service that i actually had so i can retrive it in navbar and do some validation stuffs later with the user

Comment: I just updated my previous fiddle. Here is the updated fiddle. I think this can help you. http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9802/ I just use the events for function execution when the result receive not for data transfer. Hope you understand. I have low reputation please don't forget to upvote

Comment: i solved it with the above response, but thank you for your patience friend :)